# Given the following language L, provide a CFG or prove it isn't context free

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I was shown this at university lecture as a optional challenge problem but have no idea how to work it out.

Let L be the language `L = {apbqapbq : p,q >= 0}`. Is this language context-free?
Either give a context-free grammar for it or prove that it is not context-free.

I know that `L = {apbp:p >= 1}` is a context free language but the language in the question uses 2 variables and could also equal 0, making me think that it's not context free.

Should I be using pumping lemma? Any help and explanations would be appreciated

Comment: It's not. Yes you can prove this with the pumping lemma for context free languages.  See the proof for a^n b^n c^n in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages. The proof here is very similar.  Use s = a^p b^p a^p b^p.  It's not hard to show that this choice always allows pumping to generate a string not in L. I'll let you have the fun of working out the details.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, it was very helpful!